# Размещение одного блока над другим

Tags: html, css, blocks

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно разместить блоки как на картинке?

```css
.wrapper__phone {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 21px;
  float: right;
  color: #2f1059;
}

.wrapper__phone__button {
  height: 38px;
  width: 156px;
  border: 1px solid #2f1059;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding-left: 31px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
  color: #2f1059;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper__phone">
  +7 (495) 544-23-12
  <div class="wrapper__phone__button">
    Заказать звонок
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А.. картинка где?

Comment: Точно, исправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно было обернуть номер телефона в `<p></p>`, чуть-чуть исправил кнопку

```css
.wrapper__phone {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 21px;
  float: right;
  color: #2f1059;
}

.wrapper__phone a {
  border: 1px solid #2f1059;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper__phone">
  <p>+7 (495) 544-23-12</p>
  <a href="#">Заказать звонок</a>
</div>
```